# I installed Xubuntu and can't find how to make a bootable usb on it to un-install Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

I installed Xubuntu and am not a huge fan of it.

I want Ubuntu back and can't figure out how to make a bootable usb on Xubuntu.

Please tell me my options

Comment: Just as hint - there is no need to reinstall - you can easily have 1 installation which offers several different desktop environments (i.e. Gnome Shell, Unity, XFCE etc) You can choose on the login-screen which to use if you have several installed.

Comment: If you still want to create the USB, here is a link:  https://xubuntublog.wordpress.com/tag/usb-creator/

Answer (score 10):

You could also use "Startup Disk Creator". This comes with the standard Ubuntu desktop but you should be able to use apt-get to install it in other flavours.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

Comment: Best answer. Easy download and easy program to use. No CLI gymnastics required.

Answer (score 5):

No need to reinstall the OS, I feel that it is unnecessary. You can install various desktop environments in xubuntu.
**Installing unity in xubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

**Installing gnome3 in xubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

You can choose between various desktop environments while logging in

Comment: Alternative to that would be `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` , which gives full package of the default Ubuntu installation. See related question I've asked a while back http://askubuntu.com/q/793886/295286

Answer (score 4):

Although no need to reinstall Ubuntu the answer to your question is:

You can `dd` the iso to USB which is enough for it to be bootable. If you do not mind using command line you can create a bootable usb with:

```
dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct bs=1M
```

Replace `sdx` with the whatever the target usb device is called when plugged in (use `lsblk` command to check) and notice that it is not the partition but the device itself.

Another option in Unetbootin.

Make sure to select destination device carefully, as this command **deletes all data** on the target device.